# How to put Horizontal Line under two sibling <p> tag

Tags: html, css

I have following html for my view.

```css
p {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>The first paragraph.</p>
  <p>The second paragraph.</p>
  <p>The third paragraph.</p>
  <p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions do not support the :nth-child() selector.</p>
</div>
```

I am not allowed to make any change in the html. I want a line after every two

tags as per the image below.(The number of p tags are not limited to four. They can increase.)

[image]

Can someone please tell me how to do it? Or is it even possible?

Comment: "not allowed to make any change in the html." You can at least add a class or Id to <p>?

Comment: "I am not allowed to make any change in the html" then what suggestions will you accept for this ?

Comment: Will they always be in two columns?

Comment: "not allowed to make any change in the html."  by this I mean that I can not add any extra tag in the html. Though I can add classes on the p tag.

Comment: Is there a reason you mention IE8 in your question?

Comment: @j08691 He just pasted his assignment as it is.

Comment: NO. This is just random text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way using the `::after` pseudo-element and pseudo class `nth-of-type`:

```css
p {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

p:nth-of-type(2n)::after {
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
  width: 200%;
  margin-left: -100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>The first paragraph.</p>
  <p>The second paragraph.</p>
  <p>The third paragraph.</p>
  <p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions do not support the :nth-child() selector.</p>
  <p>The first paragraph.</p>
  <p>The second paragraph.</p>
  <p>The third paragraph.</p>
  <p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions do not support the :nth-child() selector.</p>
  <p>The first paragraph.</p>
  <p>The second paragraph.</p>
  <p>The third paragraph.</p>
  <p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions do not support the :nth-child() selector.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @sk01 will fail if the first P is bigger in content: https://jsfiddle.net/3fLqwbdg/

Comment: First p is always shorter than the second p in my case. Great catch though :)

Comment: you can also ommit the width definition since it's a block level element

Answer (score 3):

```
div {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
div p {
    max-width: 50%;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: This code is putting everything in the single row. :(

Comment: @sk01 add flex-wrap:wrap

Answer (score 0):

I have tried something. Added class for Paragraph tag.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
    <style>
        p {
            width: 50%;
            float: left;
        }
.sample_line {
    border-bottom: solid;
    max-height: 18px;
    overflow: auto;
}
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div>
        <p class="sample_line">The first paragraph.</p>
        <p class="sample_line">The second paragraph.</p>
        <p class="sample_line">>The third paragraph.</p>
        <p class="sample_line">><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions do not support the :nth-child() selector.</p>

    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea with box-shadow:

```css
p {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

p:nth-child(odd) {
  clear: both;
}

div {
  overflow:auto;
  box-shadow: 0 -2px 0 black inset;
}

p:nth-child(n+3) {
  box-shadow: 0 -2px 0 black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>The first paragraph.</p>
  <p>The second paragraph.</p>
  <p>The third paragraph.</p>
  <p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions do not support the :nth-child() selector.</p>
  <p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions do not support the :nth-child() selector.<b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions do not support the :nth-child() selector.</p>
  <p>The third paragraph.</p>
  <p>The third paragraph.</p>
  <p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions do not support the :nth-child() selector.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It is putting line above the text 

Comment: @sk01 check the update (you need to refresh the page)

Comment: the solution provided by @j08691 looks much cleaner.

Comment: @sk01 I am simply providing a *different* solution and covering the case where the first P can be bigger. It's up to you to choose the solution you want but keep in mind that your question will be visible to future users that may consider or need a different solution than you

Answer (score 0):

you can also use border-top and margins; so no need to bother about paragraph's height.

Anyhow, nowdays, you would use flex or grid instead float.

```css
div {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  overflow: hidden;
}

p {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  border-top: 1px solid;
  margin: -2px 0 2px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>The first paragraph.</p>
  <p>The second paragraph.</p>
  <p>The third paragraph.</p>
  <p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions do not support the :nth-child() selector.</p>
  <p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions do not support the :nth-child() selector.</p>
  <p>The last paragraph.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Just add border-bottom to p and will look like you asked. It is no other way around.

```
 p {
     border-bottom: 1px solid black;
 }
```